# Virtual host is not working in ubuntu 16.04 giving forbidden error

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Just now i have installed a virtual host in /home/invensis/test_cakephp

```
 sudo mkdir -p /home/invensis/test_cakephp
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/invensis/test_cakephp
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/invensis
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/test_cakephp.conf
```

I have changed the test_cakephp.conf like this.But the virtual host is working  properly for other than test_cakephp

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/test_cakephp.conf
    <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName test_cakephp
     DocumentRoot /home/invensis/test_cakephp/
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

After this i have used

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

And then i edited hosts by using

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

But  when i run the localhost test_cakephp i am getting the errors like You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at test_cakephp Port 80.
You don't have permission to access /favicon.ico on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at test_cakephp Port 80.

I have tried this also.But this also not working for me.
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: `DocumentRoot` should be specified without a trailing slash:

`DocumentRoot /home/invensis/test_cakephp`

You have to enable the VirtualHost and then reload again:

```
sudo a2ensite test_cakephp
sudo service apache2 reload
```

If you want to disable it again:

```
sudo a2dissite test_cakephp
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: i have did that also but i forgot to mention that